# How to get the authors name from Google books api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-books-api

When I search for the book using this link https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9780310709626 I get the author name in the details.

However when I run my code and print items I don't see the author name. I've been trying to figure out why it doesn't show from the data but I don't see any problem with my code.

```
print(searchBooks("9780310709626"))
def getBooks(id):
      url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:"
       resp = url(api + id)
       data = json.load(resp)
       print(data["items"])
```

**My code output:**

```
[{'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'JEP3sgEACAAJ', 'etag': '92vdEneJ83g', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/JEP3sgEACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': "The Beginner's Bible", 'subtitle': 'Timeless Bible Stories', 'publisher': 'Zondervan', 'publishedDate': '2005', 'description': 'Retells familiar Bible stories from the Old and New Testaments for children to enjoy.', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '0310709628'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9780310709626'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 511, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Juvenile Nonfiction'], 'averageRating': 4.5, 'ratingsCount': 2, 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JEP3sgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JEP3sgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=JEP3sgEACAAJ&dq=isbn:9780310709626&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=JEP3sgEACAAJ&dq=isbn:9780310709626&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Beginner_s_Bible.html?hl=&id=JEP3sgEACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'TW', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'TW', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=JEP3sgEACAAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}, 'searchInfo': {'textSnippet': 'Retells familiar Bible stories from the Old and New Testaments for children to enjoy.'}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'ZRgnzQEACAAJ', 'etag': 'RXYM4Rbwx+g', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/ZRgnzQEACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': "The Beginner's Bible", 'authors': ['Catherine DeVries'], 'publishedDate': '2005', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '0310709628'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9780310709626'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 511, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'averageRating': 4, 'ratingsCount': 1, 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=ZRgnzQEACAAJ&dq=isbn:9780310709626&hl=&cd=2&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=ZRgnzQEACAAJ&dq=isbn:9780310709626&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Beginner_s_Bible.html?hl=&id=ZRgnzQEACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'TW', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'TW', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=ZRgnzQEACAAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}}]
```

Comment: The authors are in the response. You can access them with `data["items"][<INDEX>]["volumeInfo"]["authors"]`

Comment: I tried that with index 0  and I get error KeyError: 'authors' it seem that it's can't find the authors name however when I try the same thing for another isbn (example 9780593433874) I get the author name

Comment: Have you considered using the Google apis python client libary?

Comment: @DaImTo can you please link me to a tutorial for client library I will try it out

Comment: Sure let me just google that for you [Python samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/tree/main/samples)  or [Docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/)   if i recall the books api doesnt require authorization so i would have a look at this sample to see how an api key is used  [youtube search](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py)   If you need help altering it for books let me know and i will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

With the `requests` library:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9780310709626'
resp = requests.get(url)
json = resp.json()

print(json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['authors'])
```

From the response you can see that `authors` is an array. To reach that array you will need to do `json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['authors']`.

As `items` is also an array, meaning that there could be multiple items in this response. You might want to write extra code to deal with that other than hard-code `index=0`.

Note that in this case, you probably won't know the schema of the response. **You should handle unexpected behaviors**. For some certain books maybe some keys are missing, `json['items']` could be an empty array, or even `items` is not in the response at all.